# Flex Mobile Pop Up Keyboard with Numbers Selected

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a Flex Mobile Application that requires users to input data into a form application.

When a user hits a certain TextInput to enter information (Phone Number for example) I would like the keyboard that pops up to automatically change to numbers for the user to select, rather then starting at the main qwerty keyboard. I am not sure if this can be done or not.

Does anyone have any advice regarding this topic?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I knew this wasn't possible.  I there a "pop-up numeric keypad" on mobile devices?  The dialer [on my phone] is a full screen. You could create your own.  Or if a native component exists; you may be able to use a NativeExtension to pop it up.

Comment: Do you use a number validator on your text input? I.e. just to only allow numbers... i noticed some bug where if you hold down E to get the number 3, and then T to get 5, you will just get 3. Its a bother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but I do not believe we have control of that at the moment for flash mobile.  If I am indeed right, your best bet would be to create your own keyboard overlay with 1-9 numbers on it.  Then append the information to the textfield as you press the buttons.